# Getting started with Blender Texture Painting

Tags: texturing

From my experience, there seem to be multiple annoyances with painting models in other applications such as `Substance Painter`. Thus, I am looking into the viability of Blender's texture painting system to paint one of my models.

What *resources*, *addons* and *brush sets* can the community recommend beginners, intermediate and advanced users use when painting their models in Blender?

Comment: Wrong place to ask questions like that because any answers would be opinion-based. Try BlenderArtists.org or similar.

Comment: The question is too broad because you ask for beginners to pros, about addons, resources (=> https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15355/107598), and brushes... Also, we don't know what your model is ... a house? An ax? A human? Clothes? Generally, a good start is to bake some base colors with AO and/or Pointiness nodes in Cycles. With masks, you can then overpaint it in a non-destructive way.